# Water from coolant system leaking under engine block

Tags: cooling-system, leak, head-gasket

[image]

Water pissing out under engine block instantly after water poured into the cooling system.

Has something came loose or is cause for real concern and a high-cost repair? In which car will sadly have to be scrapped.

The car has been losing water but not to this extent so something has clicked in a bad way.  Recently temperature gauge has been going up, haven't driven very much.

But car essentially broke down today.

Appreciate any response.

Comment: Pic from above?

Comment: With that much I’d assume a hole in the hose or something that that

Comment: Is that an oil cooler built into the oil filter fitting? If so, it may be able to be replaced - it may have failed due to corrosion. It would help to know what vehicle etc and better pics...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely blew the bearing in the water pump, it's a possibility. I'd check out your timing area and see if your timing chain / belt is loose and see if you have play with the gear on the water pump. To make sure it's not headgasket do a pressure test on each cylinder.